# Testing CloudFront in Europe

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bandwidth, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to set up CloudFront so that European users can download from my S3 bucket quickly.

I've already set it up and am now testing. To test, I have created a Windows EC2 instance and based it in Frankfurt, I have then RDP'd into it and checked the internet speed with this:

http://www.speedtest.net

The result was 20Mbps, which is not that fast. I'm pretty sure it was downloading from a European server to, so it should have been faster. I believe the culprit is that I am using the free-tier EC2 instance to test, and this has "Low to Moderate" Network Performance. Do you think that's why I am seeing slow speeds?

In order to test whether my S3 bucket serves content fast to European users, do you think the best course is to get a EC2 with high network performance?

Thanks

Comment: That's not so bad for an internet connection from a t2.micro. Try a couple of runs, you can manually select your test server. You could also try from and m4.large or similar to see if it's faster. [Bandwidth chart](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html).

Comment: yes, t2.micro has slower network than larger ones. But i get 20MB/s from S3, 8x what you got from speedtest.net. Why dont you compare your S3 bucket and Cloufront distro directly?

Comment: also are your clients on ec2 instances too?

Comment: If I remember right, a t2.micro only has a network bandiwidth <= 250 Mbps (31.25 MB/s).  (Not published info, you have to set up instances of three different types and iperf between them to triangulate how much bandwidth each one really has available.)

Comment: I think network bandwidth is assigned relative to cores and total bandwidth. So if it's a 64 core server with a 40Gbps network, and you have 10% of a core, you get 40Gbps / 64 cores / 10% = 62Mbps. Now I know those numbers are incorrect, as I personally have gotten over 70Mbps from a t2.micro, but you get the idea. You can [benchmark it yourself](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/).